# Rails 3 Routing Resources with Variable Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to have a variable namespace? I have restful resources like the following:

```
resources :articles
resources :persons
```

But I need to scope these inside a variable namespace, such that it responds to URLs of the form:

```
':edition/:controller/:action/:id'
```

for example:

`/foobar/article/edit/123` or `/bazbam/person/edit/345`

for each of the resources. Is this possible with the `resources` method, or must I hand-craft these? I will not know the possible values for `:edition` ahead of time; these get looked up in a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController`.

Is this all I need to do?

```
scope ':edition' do
  resources :articles
  resources :matches
  resources :teams
end
```

**UPDATE: When using the scope directive above, I get routes like I want:**

```
    articles GET    /:edition/articles(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
             POST   /:edition/articles(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
 new_article GET    /:edition/articles/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
edit_article GET    /:edition/articles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
     article GET    /:edition/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
             PUT    /:edition/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
             DELETE /:edition/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
     matches GET    /:edition/matches(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"matches"}
             POST   /:edition/matches(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"matches"}
   new_match GET    /:edition/matches/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"matches"}
  edit_match GET    /:edition/matches/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"matches"}
       match GET    /:edition/matches/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"matches"}
             PUT    /:edition/matches/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"matches"}
             DELETE /:edition/matches/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"matches"}
       teams GET    /:edition/teams(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"teams"}
             POST   /:edition/teams(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"teams"}
    new_team GET    /:edition/teams/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"teams"}
   edit_team GET    /:edition/teams/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"teams"}
        team GET    /:edition/teams/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"teams"}
             PUT    /:edition/teams/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"teams"}
             DELETE /:edition/teams/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"teams"}
```

I'm now able to reference `:edition` in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :get_edition

  def get_edition
    @edition = Edition.first(:conditions => { :FriendlyName => params[:edition] } )
  end

end
```

Now I just want to make sure this is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: But what does params[:edition] resolve to? Is it seriously foobar or bazbam? If so then win! I learned something!

Comment: The `scope ':edition'` really works! But lots of troubles raises in url helpers, eg: `link_to("View Article", @article)`, `form_for(@article)`, and `redirect_to(@article)` would raise error. I think the design purpose of `scope` is for static namespaces. Why don't you just append the edition to the end of url as a param? It would save your time if following the rails way.

Comment: @Kevin - I really want to keep the URLs RESTful, and in my case, each resource is indeed unique with respect to :edition, so this does not contracdict the intent of REST. Passing as a param could work, but I wanted to keep the URLs as humane as possible. Another option would be to allow the user to switch editions via a dropdown in the application.html.erb and store that value in a cookie.

Comment: Yes @Mark, you're right. You can choose a comfortable approach according to your requirement, and the `scope` method really works, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just do the following :

```
my_var = "persons"
resources my_var.to_sym
```

The `to_sym` method on a string changes it to a symbol

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the possible values for edition - then you can't use namespaces which seem like they might have solved this issue.

That said, I'd just handcraft them - your case here seems like the ideal case foregoing resources and going straight to a handcrafted path.