# Rails 3 routing from root show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently

```
Project101::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/:id' => 'companies#show'
  resources :companies do 
    resources :customers
    resources :users
    resources :categories
    resources :addresses
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :controller => "users"

  root :to => "companies#index"
end
```

Everything belongs to a company.  Trying to create routes like www.example.com/:id/customers where :id is always the company id.

At the moment www.example.com/:id works but all url's are generated as /companies/:id/cusotmers.

Saw [Rails 3 Routing Resources with Variable Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440179/rails-3-routing-resources-with-variable-namespace).

Is this the right way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Kept :as => :company to help generate the URL's, Links, etc a little easier for me.  Sure others could do cleaner or better method.  Also had to manually create the edit, destroy, new with different urls so I could use them in links if user was admin.

```
Project101::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/' => 'companies#index'
  match '/companies' => 'companies#index'
  match '/:company_id' => 'companies#show', :as => :show_company
  match '/companies/:id/edit' => 'companies#edit', :as => :edit_company
  match '/companies/:id/new' => 'companies#new', :as => :new_company
  match '/companies/:id/destroy' => 'companies#destroy', :as => :delete_company

  scope '/:company_id', :as => :company do 
    resources :customers
    resources :users
    resources :categories
    resources :services
    resources :addresses
  end  
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :controller => "users"
  root :to => "companies#index"    
end
```

Then just used basic nested_resources for links, controllers and forms.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_company

  def current_company
    if params[:company_id] != nil 
      @current_company ||= Company.find(params[:company_id])
    else
      @current_company = nil
    end
    return @current_company
  end
end
```

Basic links 
 `<%= link_to "Customers", company_customers_path(current_company) %>`

links for specific customer 
 `<%= link_to @customer.name, edit_company_customer_path(current_company, @customer) %>`

Controllers look like

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @company = current_company
    @customer = @company.customers.new
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created customer."
      redirect_to company_customer_path(current_company, @customer)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my forms look like

```
<%= form_for [@company, @customer] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you always want the routes to begin with the company id you can wrap them in a scope like this:

```
scope ":company_id" do
    resources :customers
    resources :users
    resources :categories
    resources :addresses
end
```

Comment: when adding it your way I get routes like /:id/companies/:id/customers etc.  Close but longer than what I was looking for.  What I am trying now is scope ":id", :as => :company do which gives me /:id/customers.    which is easier to read but having to match every action manually for company.  guess that's the trade of.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I edited the code above to remove the `resources :companies` portion.  Also, you can't have two :id parameters, so I renamed the one in the scope to :company_id.

Comment: This could definitely work.  How do you think I can pass this :company_id to my controllers and links?  As it is If I force the url to /:company_id/customers/new it then redirects to /customers without the :company_id